# Excel if and or function together

Tags: excel, formula

I have data where D5, D6, D7 and D8 can either be "Y" or "N", depending on what combination is in these fields I want to return either "Not applicable", "Date of election", or "No payment".

As Y,Y,Y,Y would return "Not applicable" as would the combination Y,Y,Y,N I have got this far:

**=IF(D5="Y",IF(D6="Y",IF(D7="Y",IF(D8="Y","Not applicable",IF(D5="Y",IF(D6="Y",IF(D7="Y",IF(D8="N","Not applicable",""))))))))**

My issue is to expand beyond this to cover the rest of the scenarios. Any tips greatly appreciated.

Thank you

*EDIT*

Sorry. I was trying not to make it too complicated. The full acceptable combinations for each result are as follows:

**Not applicable**

Y,Y,Y,Y

Y,Y,Y,N

N,Y,Y,N

N,Y,N,Y

**Date of election**

Y,Y,N,Y

Y,N,Y,Y

Y,N,N,Y

N,Y,Y,Y

N,N,Y,Y

N,N,N,Y

Comment: You only covered 10 of the 16 possible combinations.  I assume all other will be deemed "No Payment"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a small table that has the various combinations and their expected outcome:

[image]

Then use a VLOOKUP inside IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D5&D6&D7&D8,G:H,2,FALSE),"No Payment")
```

This has the benefit that the values are not hard coded and can be changed if need arises without parsing the formula.

[image]

Comment: @MikeJC please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.   It is something only the one who posed the question can do.